# How to write a query which icludes OR with AND condition in ILIKE search query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to write query for search, with includes more than 1 parameters, i wanna search based on that parameters using 'AND' and 'OR' operator and get data using ILIKE.
My query is: 
`TableName.where("( first_name ILIKE ? OR last_name ILIKE ? AND concat_ws(' ', address1, address2, city, state, country) ILIKE ?  )", "%"+name+"%", "%"+last_name+"%", "%"+address+"%")`

Comment: What is your question? If there's an error here, please show it. Also note that ILIKE is supported in Postgres, it won't work on MySQL.

Comment: my question is how to add parenthesis in this query to work with the combinations of  'AND' and 'OR' conditions. ILIKE / LIKE does't matter in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
("( (first_name ILIKE ? OR last_name ILIKE ?) AND concat_ws(' ', address1, address2, city, state, country) ILIKE ?  )", "%"+name+"%", "%"+last_name+"%", "%"+address+"%")
```

I just added parentheses around the name condition, so essentially it's saying "either name must match" AND "address must also match"

(Side note  it would be unusual to see an address condition like that - if there's any user input involved, they'll rarely match the exact address.)

Comment: thanks, I think second '?' needs to be inside parenthesis before 'ILIKE'

Comment: true! that's fixed